# CAML query with more than multiple AND/OR generates SPException "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."

Tags: spquery, caml-query

I need to build a CAML query at runtime based on user input. The CAML query could be as simple as

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Status" />
    <Value Type="Text">Awaiting Completion</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

or might include multiple AND and OR like

```
<Where>
  <Or>
    <Or>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Status" />
        <Value Type="Text">Awaiting Completion</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Status" />
        <Value Type="Text">Ongoing</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Or>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="status" />
      <Value Type="Text">Postponed</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

The problem is that as soon as I add a third Status to check as in the query above it generates an SPException

> "One or more field types are not
>   installed properly. Go to the list
>   settings page to delete these fields"

A quick code snippet to reproduce the problem:

```
   using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://sp2010"))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb("/test"))
                {
                    SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
                    spQuery.Query = "<Where><Or><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">Awaiting Completion</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">Ongoing</Value></Eq></Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"status\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">Postponed</Value></Eq></Or></Where>";                    
                    SPListItemCollection spListItemCollection = spWeb.Lists["Actions"].GetItems(spQuery);
                    foreach(SPListItem spListItem in spListItemCollection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(spListItem.Title);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe in 3rd <Eq> you should use "Status" instead of "status".

Comment: @Andriy Shvay: You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'm turning my comment into answer.

Onse in a while we all are making a typos - to solve your problem you should use "Status" instead of "status" in 3rd `<Eq>`.

Comment: Ha! Brilliant I spent so long getting my xml balanced in pairs of ANDs and ORs that I completely looked past the typo. Thank you very much.

Comment: Therefore I use Camlex.NET (http://camlex.codeplex.com) in my c# code as well as something like U2U Query Builder to check and test CAML queries.